Series about people who get infected with worms
Around 2015, I was on vacation, and I watched a series on television. Unfortunately, I only saw the first view episodes of the (mini-)series.
The series was about a plane that landed at an airport. The people on the plane all died, so a big investigation was started, but after a while the people came back to life, sort of. The people were infected with some kind of worm. The people who were infected now listened to a leader who was also on the plane, in a coffin.
I can also remember that no one knew what was going on except for an old man with a sword as a cane.
